# Cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String)

Tags: java

Не могу понять в чем проблема моей попытки кода, но в Main классе не работает
 area.getText(na.l);

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Na na = new Na();
    JFrame kl = new JFrame();
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    area.getText (na.l);
    /* тут (na.l) подчеркивается красным, а при наведении курсора пишет это предложение. */
}
}


class Na {
    Main maiin = new Main();
    String l = "Rain";
}
```

Comment: Таки get или всё же set? Если первое, то, наверняка, нема версии метода с к-л аргументом.

Comment: метод **get**Text() не имеет аргументов., он возвращает текущее текстовое содержимое объекта, если объект вообще может содержать текст и имеет такой геттер

Answer (score 1):

У класса `JTextArea` есть два метода `getText`:

```
public String getText()
```

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText())

и

```
public String getText(int offs, int len) throws BadLocationException
```

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText(int,%20int))

Метода `getText` с одним аргументом типа `String` этот класс не имеет. Отсюда и ошибка.

Подозреваю, что Вам надо либо

```
na.l = area.getText();
```

либо

```
area.setText(na.l);
```

Последнее использует метод

```
public void setText(String t)
```

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String))